# Simulate left click in java?

Tags: java

I'm struggling to figure out how to stimulate a left click in java, any help appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
Robot KeyPresser = new Robot();
KeyPresser.???
```

The only things that show after InputEvent for me are InputEvent.mouseInputEvent or InputEvent.keyInputEvent

Comment: Why don't you try the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress(int))?

Comment: I did, but for some reason if I put KeyPresser.mousePress(BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) it throws BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field. And yes it even does so after putting KeyEvent or InputEvent prior to it

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39175038/edit) your question to clarify the problem. Did you make sure to import `java.awt.event.InputEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check for documentation, it's available.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131427/java-robot-class-simulating-human-mouse-movement)
[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java)
here is an example of how to use robot

```
    try{

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    // mouse move
    robot.mouseMove(x,y);// x,y are cordinates 
    // Simulate a mouse click
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    // Simulate a key press
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did already know this but for some reason BUTTON1_MASK shows as an incorrect field.

Comment: The only things that show after InputEvent for me are InputEvent.mouseInputEvent or InputEvent.keyInputEvent